# Почему не заполняется кросс-таблица 1С?

Tags: 1с

Мне нужно сделать кросс-таблицу с пользователями и их статусом, действителен ли он. Если он действителен, то в колонке ничего не нужно писать, если недействителен, то значение `"Истина"`.

```
               | Пользователь 1 | Пользователь 2 | Пользователь 3
Недействителен | Истина         |                | Истина
```

Но как это сделать? Сейчас пока получается только так сделать:

```
Недействителен | Пользователь 1 | Пользователь 2 | Пользователь 3
Да             |                |                | 
Нет            |                |                |
```

Но значения внутри таблицы не вычисляются. Что я делаю не так?

Вот запрос:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    Пользователи.Наименование КАК Наименование,
    Пользователи.Недействителен КАК Недействителен
ИЗ
    Справочник.Пользователи КАК Пользователи
```

Вот так выглядят настройки:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании СКД, на пересечении строк и колонок выводятся ресурсы (см. соответствующую вкладку).

[Пример разработки отчета в системе компоновки данных](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/1452/hdoc)